# Info Pane: How to copy output?

Tags: scripting, interface

When I perform actions, the Info pane at the top outputs the equivalent python commands.

If i try to select the text to copy, It won't allow the selection.

Is there a way to configure this to work?
[image: text to copy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the line you want to copy, and it will highlight. Press ctrl-C to copy and then also right click it again to deselect it or otherwise it will copy every line that is highlighted next time you highlight and copy. Paste it into the text editor, etc.

Comment: Ah Thanks! I was trying to drag-select on a track pad, guess single click only works here